# Generic way of Json to CSV converting for generic deep nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, csv

I am programing a function, that should convert generic deep nested JSON object levels to CSV file in JS or TypeScript.
I tried several libraries but somehow they don't work the way i want it to unwind the nested JSON right. The code should unwind this input:

```
{
 [
  {
     app: "app1",
     device: [
       "c1",
       "c2",
       "c3",
       "c4"
     ]
   },
   {
     app: "app2",
     device: [
       "b1",
       "b2"
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

Into this expected result:

```
app;device
app1;c1
app1;c2
app1;c3
app1;c4
app2;b1
app2;b2
```

Right now I'm using this code but the result is not like expected:

```
 private ConvertToCSV(json: string, fields: string[]): string {
    const Json2csvParser = require("json2csv").Parser;

    let options: {};

    options = { fields };

    const parser = new Json2csvParser(options);

    const csv = parser.parse(JSON.parse(json));
    console.log(JSON.parse(json));
    console.log(csv);
    return csv;
  }
```

My result right now looks like this:

```
"app","device"
"app1","[""c1"",""c2"",""c3"",""c4""]"
"app2","[""b1"",""b2""]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this -- it's right in the docs with the [unwind function](https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv#example-7) though you may need to add a transformer to format it exactly how you want. Take a look:

```
const data: any = [
  {
     app: "app1",
     device: [
       "c1",
       "c2",
       "c3",
       "c4"
     ]
   },
   {
     app: "app2",
     device: [
       "b1",
       "b2"
     ]
   }
 ];

function ConvertToCSV(json: string, fields: any): string {
  const Json2csvParser = require("json2csv").parse;

  let options: {};

  options = fields;

  const csv = Json2csvParser(JSON.parse(json), options);
  console.log(JSON.parse(json));
  console.log(csv);
  return csv;
}

ConvertToCSV(JSON.stringify(data), {fields: ['app', 'device'], unwind: 'device'});
```

Let me know if this solves your issue, or if it doesn't. I have some experience with this lib and may be able to help

Comment: do you know how to covert the unwinded data back to a proper json?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend flattening your data and then just using the csv parser you have.

```
function flattenData(data,groupingField,flattenedField) {
  let flattenedData =[];
  data.forEach(d => {
    d[flattenedField].forEach(sd => {
      flattenedData.push({[groupingField]: d[groupingField], [flattenedField]: sd});
    });
  });
  return flattenedData;
}
```

Then you'll have a data structure your csv parser knows how to deal with.

Comment: The library has this functionality built in

Comment: Honestly even if it did I wouldn’t rely on it. My csv parser should be simple and replaceable. It should take a simple structure and parse it into a csv and not do any opaque data mapping. I’ll find / write my own mappers to make my program less coupled with a csv parser.